# Does anyone know of any examples of the use of character counter on an input field?

Tags: input-fields, html5, counter

I am working on a project that allows users to edit objects named by clicking on it using something similar to the HTML 5 **Content-editable attribute**.

**Update:**

- The character limit is 30 not three.
- Also the input field is meant to have the counter below it much like twitter has

However we need a way to notify the users of the 30 character limit to their object name. My first hypothesis is to use a text counter like the ones twitter uses.

Are there are some examples of other techniques that we can apply or does the method applied to a textarea field work best for an input as well?

Thanks,

Comment: inside and input field? extremely NOT recommended, specially if you have a 3 character limit, where is the counter supposed to fit? Instead, you can add it below the input field, or simply add a generic warning on top, and then validate if `>3` characters

Comment: thanks sorry if I wrote inside the input field. What I meant to say was below the input field similar to what twitter does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You and [Google material design](https://www.google.com/design/spec/components/text-fields.html#text-fields-character-counter) have already described a good solution to your problem. The method applies well to both text areas and text input fields, so don't hesitate to use this approach. See the image below:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

My bank has a strict 5-digit pincode policy and the input looks like as many underscores as there are characters allowed. It's very minimalist, yet you quickly get that each corresponds to a character. Here's an approximate rendering of it:

```
A B C
_ _ _ _ _
```

Comment: I actually like that idea a great deal. Its intuitive and interesting. I think this would be a great alternative to a normal counter.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, you could use "helper text" inside your input, which describes number of characters. In my example i use "abc" text as help. 
One letter typed by the user replaces one letter of the helper text.

[image]

Comment: I like the idea of this, it is essentially just an input-mask except the placeholder remains visible. It will only work for short values though, you wont want to enforce a 300char limit with a ton of placeholder text. It also begs the question *what* default text do you use thats not confusing.

Comment: I agree that I like the idea of a placeholder mask. I don't know that we have any placeholder text that would make the most sense context wise however. Thanks guys these ideas are really helpful